# Show download button if iOS App not installed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a download button for my iOS App on my website page .

```
<a class="downloadButton" href="myAppURL">Download</a>
```

**Problem:** When user open my website on iOS device, it check if App already installed download button not display, but if App not already installed it display download button.

Any solution using jquery of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't list installed apps from a browser using js, it would be a security hole. Just show the download button to everyone and let the user decide if he wants to install your app.

Comment: Can we detect installed apps using any other method ? like any library or any other ways.